# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS', trying to find sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I checked the other questions similar to the title and could not find the answer. I am working through a software, so I unable to tweak the SQL directly, I can only change certain parts.

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @ShowZeros nVarChar(4000);

SET @ShowZeros  = 'N';

SELECT 
    IC_ProductLots.Available_Alt
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
    , IC_ProductLots.Available_Stk
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
    , IC_Products.Description1
    , IC_Products.ProductCode
    , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
    , AR_Customers.Name
    , SUM([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk]) GROUP BY [AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS [Total Stock]
FROM ((( DC_Transactions 
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
        ON DC_Transactions.CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
        ON DC_Transactions.LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_Products 
        ON DC_Transactions.ProductKey = IC_Products.ProductKey)
WHERE 
    (IC_Products.ProductCode = '      515070')  
    AND (
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN @ShowZeros = 'Y' or @ShowZeros = 'YES' THEN 1 
                ELSE (ISNULL([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk],0))
            END
        ) > 0
    )
ORDER BY 
    IC_Products.ProductCode 
  , AR_Customers.CustomerCode 
  , AR_Customers.Name
```

I am trying to find the sum of the Available stock, how ever I run into a problem with my Select sum statement:

```
 SUM([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk]) 
 GROUP BY [AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS [Total Stock]
```

The answer was found but my output is still not correct, 
It should appear as this:
Output should look similar to below:

```
Cases | U/M  | Total Stock | Description | Cust Name  | Cust Code
-----------------------------------------------------------------
57    | CS   | 1779.45     | Food        | Restaurant | 2
4     | CS   | 120         | Dough       | Bakery     | 44
```

Currently it prints out 57 lines for customer code 2 and 4 lines for customer code 44, displaying the same information for each customer code. Basically it prints out a line for every case that customer has.

Comment: I don't think you want `SUM` and `GROUP BY` in that one expression, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Andrew , when I didn't have the Group By function there I got an error saying I needed it. 
  'IC_ProductLots.Available_Alt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Austin You're putting the `GROUP BY` in the wrong place.  This goes after your `WHERE` clauses and before your `ORDER BY`.  You'll also need to add all of the other columns to your `GROUP BY` as well.

Comment: You need to list all the columns you're selecting (that don't have aggregates like max) in the group by, and it has to be after where part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your trying to use a window-function. If this is your intention, you can use this code instead:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @ShowZeros nVarChar(4000);

SET @ShowZeros  = 'N';

SELECT 
 IC_ProductLots.Available_Alt
, IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
, IC_ProductLots.Available_Stk
, IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
, IC_Products.Description1
, IC_Products.ProductCode
, AR_Customers.CustomerCode
, AR_Customers.Name
, SUM([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk]) OVER(PARTITION BY [AR_Customers].[CustomerCode]) AS [Total Stock]
 FROM ((( DC_Transactions 
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON DC_Transactions.CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON DC_Transactions.LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_Products 
     ON DC_Transactions.ProductKey = IC_Products.ProductKey)
 WHERE 
    (IC_Products.ProductCode = '      515070')  AND 
     ((CASE WHEN @ShowZeros = 'Y' or @ShowZeros = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE
 (ISNULL([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk],0))
    END) > 0)
   ORDER BY 
    IC_Products.ProductCode 
  , AR_Customers.CustomerCode 
  , AR_Customers.Name
```

The group by in the select is just wrong. I changed it to an `OVER`-clause

Comment: this worked but now I am unable to get the output I desire. I added my desired output to the question.

Comment: What is your issue? do you have duplicated rows or what is the current output? This would help. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to list all the columns which is not included in an aggregate function in the Group By clause after the Where clause

So your query will be

```
       SELECT 
     IC_ProductLots.Available_Alt
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
    , IC_ProductLots.Available_Stk
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
    , IC_Products.Description1
    , IC_Products.ProductCode
    , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
    , AR_Customers.Name
    , SUM([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk])  AS [Total Stock]
     FROM ((( DC_Transactions 
        INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
         ON DC_Transactions.CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
        INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
         ON DC_Transactions.LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
        INNER JOIN  IC_Products 
         ON DC_Transactions.ProductKey = IC_Products.ProductKey)
     WHERE 
        (IC_Products.ProductCode = '      515070')  AND 
         ((CASE WHEN @ShowZeros = 'Y' or @ShowZeros = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE
     (ISNULL([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk],0))
        END) > 0)
GROUP BY IC_ProductLots.Available_Alt
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
    , IC_ProductLots.Available_Stk
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
    , IC_Products.Description1
    , IC_Products.ProductCode
    , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
    , AR_Customers.Name
       ORDER BY 
        IC_Products.ProductCode 
      , AR_Customers.CustomerCode 
      , AR_Customers.Name
```

Comment: Maybe he wants an window-function (as it seems due to his group by inside the select). I've added a alternative solution. The question wasn't clear in that point. :-)

Comment: @ionic you are correct..i didn't thought abt that..like you said the question is not clear..